# I am trying to a servlet based application to work

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, embedded-jetty

I keep getting this error

HTTP ERROR: 404
Not Found
RequestURI=/WEB_INF/account

Powered by Jetty://

my properties is follows
projectx.webserver.contextpath=/
projectx.webserver.webapp=/opt/ProjectX/webapps/xxx

my web.xml is as follows

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>account</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.xxx.projectx.wui.servlet.AccountServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
```

my directory tree is as follows
`/opt/ProjectX/webapps/xxx/WEB-INF`

classes  web.xml

the classes dir contains

/opt/ProjectX/webapps/xxx/WEB-INF/classes/com/xxx/projectx/wui/servlet/
AccountServlet.class

and my JSP that calls the servlet in question is as follows

```
<form method="post" action="/WEB_INF/account" name="account">
```

I have tried /account,/servlet/account

I would really appreciate some help on getting this to work

Comment: Anything below WEB-INF is not visible to the outside world..  As you have servlet mapping setup in web.xml it should be OK to call it based upon *projectname/account*

Comment: see https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11035_01/wls100/webapp/configureservlet.html

Answer (score 2):

Should be configured

`<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>account</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/servlet/account</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>`

Hope to help you!

Comment: Yes, this should also be configured ;-)

Answer (score 0):

A servlet must have a servlet-mapping with it,like this:

```html
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>account</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.xxx.projectx.wui.servlet.AccountServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>account</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/account.do</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

And your form should be

```html
<form method="post" action="account.do" name="account">
```